# How to rollback changes done by one developer keeping all other changes alive?

Tags: git

All changes are already pushed to repository, now we got a bug and need to roll back all changes done by developerX to specific commit(commitX -done before 15 days).

But with this I need to preserve changes done by all other developers after commitX.

Option 1 - checkout all files of commitX and then commit older version of files.

--but there are some new files are added and some are removed by developerX in his later commits, what will happen with that ? do I need to manually remote/add those ?

Is there any other better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the undesirable changes were merged in via a pull request (or at least a non-fast-forwarded merge commit), you can reference that commits hash to create a new revert commit:

Assuming you're currently on your primary branch (likely `master`):

```
git checkout -b revert-bad-changes
git revert <hashOfMergeCommit>
# push your branch, merge it into master, whatever your process is
```

If the changes were fast-forwarded or otherwise done right in the master branch, you'll need to reference numerous commits in the `revert` command, eg:

```
git revert <badCommitHash1> <badCommitHash2> <badCommitHash3>...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git revert <commitHash>
```

this will create a new commit that revert the target commit.

more see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)